# How do I get the time difference between each of my events in a table, and return all of these difference?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a set of data in a table, including 3 columns.

`Event_Location` `Event_Type` `Event_Time`

For each event, it has a start event, and a finish event, these are stored seperately where `Event_Type` will be 1 or 2 respectively.

I'm wanting to return the location, start time, and length of time for each event. So I'll need to find the difference between each event type for the location, and return the time difference.

I've tried something like:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF((LAG(Event_Time) OVER (ORDER BY Event_Time)), Event_Time) AS differenceTime
FROM  event_table
WHERE Event_Location = 'Location_1'
```

But just nothing really returning, and I'm not sure how to loop this through all of my data in this table matching them to corresponding events

Comment: Show us some sample table data and also its expected result - all as properly formatted text (no images, no links.) I.e. a [mcve].

Comment: @watson welcome :-) Please do not describe your data. Show us a sample of it. Makes it much easier to provide a usable code answer.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3

Comment: The published code is behaving as expected see https://dbfiddle.uk/WHdT4ytl see date functions for more appropriate functions, and I suppose what you want is not what the question asks.

Comment: The `time difference` will be calculated by `TIMEDIFF()`, `DATEDIFF()` returns difference in days.